# Autofill column excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

What is the formula to autofill (autoincrement) the No. column when pemesanan column are already filled? I use a google spreadsheet

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by myself.
I'm using `=ARRAYFORMULA(condition;true_condition;false_condition)`

in my case I'm using this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(C5:C="";"";ROW(B5:B)-4))`

Answer (score 0):

Using cell B8 as an example to drag down:

=IF(LEN(C8)>0,1+B7,"")

Comment: I already edit my question, can you make the answer clearly?

Comment: Just made an update. Should be able to put that formula in B8 and drag down.

Comment: I already use your formula but ERROR, I use google spreadsheet

Comment: Made another update and tested in Google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

As you serial no. starts from `B5` cell then you can use below formula.

```
=IF(C5<>"",ROW()-4,"")
```